# Multiple image sizes from one uploaded image?

Tags: 7, media

In my content type, I've got an image uploader. That image then gets processed by an Image Style that scales the image. I want to produce multiple scaled sizes of that image though. So essentially, I need to assign multiple Image Styles to that one image upload. In the UI, I can only assign one. This is Drupal 7, by the way.

So, for example: I start by uploading an 800x600 image and I've applied an Image Style to output it at 400x300. Now I want to apply another Image Style to get a 200x150 version. And so on...

Surely, I'm missing something here! Seems like a straightforward request. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Image derivatives are created on-demand when they are requested, so it possible to do anything you want, but we need some more information on what that is.

Comment: For example: I start by uploading an 800x600 image and I've applied an Image Style to output it at 400x300. Now I want to apply another Image Style to get a 200x150 version. (appended to question) 

But I'm intrigued by your comment of "Image derivatives are created on-demand when they are requested". How do I request them? Specifically, how in a content template?

Comment: Hang on... I might be looking for something like this function: image_style_url($style_name, $path) http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

Comment: Confirmed! @MPD Thanks! I Googled for "drupal request image derivative" and found the answer immediately.

Comment: Hi, Sam. Can you please write more details about using the image_style_url() function? Are you using any specific hook? A snippet of your code will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function that I was looking for:

```
image_style_url($style_name, $path)
```

More info [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7).

(*Should have done a little more digging via Google before I asked!*)

Answer (score 1):

```
drush image-flush
```

is a very useful command to regenerate all images associated to any defined Image Style. Use

```
drush image-flush -h
```

for details.